# how i can calculate age in java from JDateChooser

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jdatechooser

i want to calculate age but this result = 0. 
this is my code

```
Date tgl = rs.getDate("Tanggal_Lahir");//take from database
            Date kini = new Date();
            int umur = kini.getYear()-tgl.getYear();//.getyear have strikethrough
```

someone can give solution.thx

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with `JDateChooser`, but the strike-through indicates the method is deprecated: the API recommends using `Calendar` instead. What data type is the Date in the database?

Comment: What is the actual date value in the database?

Comment: Tanggal_Lahir value is date

Comment: What is the value of `tgl.getYear()`? Is the year of `tgl` correct?

Comment: yeah,but this result  = 0

Comment: What *is* the value of `tgl.getYear()`? Use `System.out.println(tgl.getYear())` as debug statement.

Comment: Use an appropriate library, like Java 8's Time API or Joda-Time